# can't apply style maxHeight in javascript (calc)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to apply a maxHeight via js and using calc.
The problem is it doesn't apply anything.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pqgQEe

```
var div = document.getElementById("toto2");
var offtop = div.offsetTop;
var offHei = div.offsetHeight;

console.log("calc('500px-"+(Math.abs(offtop-offHei))+"px');");


div.style.maxHeight="calc('500px-"+(Math.abs(offtop-offHei))+"px');"
console.log(div.style.maxHeight)
```

Why I am using calc, is because I will use 100% or 100vh in code, and I need it to work using calc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need remove `"` `;` and write proper format of `calc` with whitespace

```js
var div = document.getElementById("toto2");
var offtop = div.offsetTop;
var offHei = div.offsetHeight;

console.log("calc(500px - "+(Math.abs(offtop-offHei))+"px");


div.style.maxHeight="calc(500px - "+(Math.abs(offtop-offHei))+"px)"
console.log(div.style.maxHeight)
```

```css
#toto1{
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  background-color:red;
  overflow:auto;
}

#toto2{
  top:300px;
  position:relative;
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%; height:100%;">
  <div id="toto1">  
    <div id="toto2"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. 
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be foundin the LICENSE file at http://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/license.
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add white space and remove ''

Edit!

```
div.style.maxHeight="calc(500px - "+(Math.abs(offtop-offHei))+"px)"
```

Comment: you need remove ; (div.style.maxHeight="calc(500px - "+(Math.abs(offtop-offHei))+"px);")